# Filter a view on field on a user referenced entity

Tags: 8, views

Given:

- A view with some field
- A field with referenced entity on user entity, named: `assigner`
- A filter on the field `assigner`

How i can filter by a list of user? if i apply the same filter on `Authored by` it works.

The only option view edit form shows me is a filter on text base input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding a filter on the user name you need a relationship for your field `assigner`. This in the advanced section of views. After you have set up the relationship:

**User referenced from field_assigner**

You can add a filter:

**Name (autocomplete)**

and choose the relationship:

**field_assigner: User**